# If back button pressed, alert show and application closes

Tags: android

I have code for quiz, if `back button` pressed, `alert` show and application closes which is the flow of the application.
But i have problem, if back button pressed, then it is not responding and executing the code.
help me, thanks.

public class GandaActivity  extends Activity {

```
List<Question> quesList;
ArrayList<Integer> questIdRandom;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
int randomIdSoal=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ganda_layout);
    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();


    Collections.shuffle(quesList);

    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tQuestion);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.groupRadio);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            if(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){

            }
            else if(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                grp.clearCheck();
                if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                    //Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                }
                if (qid < 10) {
                    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GandaActivity.this, ResultQuizGanda.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}

private void setRandomSoal(){
    int size = quesList.size();
    int sizeRandom = 0;
    Log.d("TOTAL SOAL","Jumlah soal "+size);

    while(sizeRandom<10){
        int id = new Random().nextInt(size);
        if(sizeRandom==0){
            questIdRandom.add(id);
        }else if(cekQuestRandomId(id)){
            questIdRandom.add(id);
        }
        sizeRandom = questIdRandom.size();
    }


}

private boolean cekQuestRandomId(int id){
    boolean cek = false;

    int sizeRandom = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(sizeRandom<10){
        if(sizeRandom==0){
            cek = false;
        }else if(questIdRandom.get(i)==id){
            cek = false;
        }else{
            cek = true;
        }
        sizeRandom = questIdRandom.size();
        i++;
    }
    return cek;
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Apakah anda yakin ingin keluar?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

thanks, please help me!

Comment: can you please upload logs.

Comment: Are you sure control goes into `if` section. Is `getRepeatCount == 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()` method then move the code inside your `onKeyDown()` method to `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Apakah anda yakin ingin keluar?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
       builder.create().show();

}
```

I added this `builder.create().show();` to your code to be able to show the dialog.